# Doctrine 1.2: Save record from POST: validation error on integer model field

Tags: php, doctrine

i'm creating my Doctrine record this way:

```
$user = new User();
$user->fromArray($_POST);
$user->save();
```

This throws an exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Validator_Exception' with message 'Validation failed in class User 1 field had validation error: * 1 validator failed on dni (type)
```

Of course, the "dni" field is of type: integer, and the HTTP POST has all the values as strings. This is what makes the validation fail. The only way of passing the validation is doing this:

```
$_POST['dni'] = (int) $_POST['dni'];
```

But it "feels" wrong.
As a note, I'm working with Doctrine integrated into CodeIgniter. This didn't ever happened to me when worked with Symfony.

Many thanks.

Comment: For now I changed the "dni" field to string type. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old but unanswered so here it is:

`$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_VALIDATE, VALIDATE_ALL & ~VALIDATE_TYPES);`

You can instruct Doctrine to validate all or no combination of: Types (your issue), Length, Constraints, All and None.

You can do it on the [global level](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/pl#validator).

Probably also on the connection level.

And definetly per table but I could not find it on the [doctrine orm documentation](http://www.symfonyreference.com/schema-yml#attributes-42).

**and you don't need to worry about having a wrong data type inserted in the database, the db won't let you and that's outside of doctrine's hand.**

Comment: Yes, it's an old question but the answer is very useful! Thank you very much!

Comment: @bksunday Thank you for this answer and stay safe. You saved few hours of head-scratching. To anyone trying to find the doc referred look here.
https://web.archive.org/web/20120622221713/http://www.symfonyreference.com/schema-yml#attributes-42